# Quantlib and utils cannot import name 'to_datetime'

Tags: python, libraries, quantlib

I am trying to re-excecute the notebbok explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Lc5r0YxAME&index=3&list=PLu_PrO8j6XAvOAlZND9WUPwTHY_GYhJVr). However I get the error message when I try to import to_datetime form utils library which is correctely installed on my system (Win 7 enterprise).

```py
from QuantLib import *

import pandas as pd
import utils
from utils import to_datetime, format_rate
utils.set_default_plot_size()

from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter
```

What I get is the usual `ImportError`

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-230e0aaadc54> in <module>()
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import utils
----> 5 from utils import to_datetime, format_rate
      6 utils.set_default_plot_size()
      7 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Stocazzo'
```

any idea for solution?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. But do you have a file called utils.py, and does it contain a function called to_datetime?

Comment: Sorry, it was meant as a picture of the error log. I am looking for such a file, but the one I find does not contain that function.

Comment: what exactly is utils module? it may be some custom module, writrwn by video authors, or I'm wrong? what do `import utils` and `dir(utils)` say?

Comment: same for error log, it has to be text, not picture, @Oscar

Answer (score 1):

The module `utils.py` imported in the video contains a few small functions that I don't define explicitly in each notebook in order to reduce verbosity.  It's available for download with the [QuantLib Python Cookbook](https://leanpub.com/quantlibpythoncookbook), together with the notebooks themselves.  The module you have on your system is probably a different one with the same name.

If you don't want to get the cookbook, the function is simple enough to write yourself.  Given a QuantLib Date object `d`, you have to return `datetime.date(d.year(), d.month(), d.dayOfMonth())`.